# How to add a variable to location.href when creating new buttons in jquery?

Tags: onclick, location, href, attr

I am adding new buttons in jquery and each button should have its own specific url. But adding a variable to the URL seems to be a problem.

I searched numerous sites and pages. No solution found. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'includes/Get_number_of_days.inc.php',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response){
    var len = response.length;
    for (var a = 0; a < len; a++) {
        var afdeling = response[a].Competitie_Naam_Kort;
        var y = response[a].Speelweek;
        var newbutton = $('<input/>').attr({
                 type: "button",
                 value: a,
                 id: afdeling + y,
                 class: "button-" + afdeling + y,
                 onClick: "/ADL/Competitie/Uitslagen.html?" + afdeling + y
                });
        newbutton.appendTo(div);
     }
}
```

});

The buttons show up all right, but nothing happens when I click them. It must have to do something with the syntax in onClick: "/ADL/Competitie/Uitslagen.html?" + afdeling + y. But I can't figure out what the correct syntax should be. All help greatly appreciated of course...

Comment: So, in short, the question is: How do I replace the 12 in     onClick: "/ADL/Competitie/Uitslagen.html?A12" by a variable ?

Comment: So, after another few hours of searching and cursing, I found the answer myself. It should be: onClick: 'location.href=\' ' + link + '\' '.